# Scraping Data from an Unstructured PDF

Tags: python, pdf, screen-scraping

I am currently working on a project using the Government Publishing Office's "Plum Book," which documents all appointed government positions. Using Stata, our goal is to calculate the proportion of appointees with certain types of appointments within each individual office.

The 2020 and 2016 Plum Books have Excel sheets available online, which were easy to use in Stata. However, all Plum Books earlier than 2016 are only listed in PDF or txt format. While they are semi-structured, the department and office subsections are listed above groups of entries rather than as their own columns for each entry. My goal is to scrape the data from these PDFs or txt files and reorganize them so that each entry has a department and office designation. There are too many entries to do this by hand.

I will include link to the PDF format and an example Excel sheet as the outcome I am seeking to replicate. There are also some other file types included on the government website, [MODS](https://www.govinfo.gov/metadata/pkg/GPO-PLUMBOOK-2020/mods.xml) and [PREMIS](https://www.govinfo.gov/metadata/pkg/GPO-PLUMBOOK-2020/premis.xml), but as I am new to coding, I am not sure how these might be used.

PDF: https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-PLUMBOOK-2012/pdf/GPO-PLUMBOOK-2012.pdf
txt: https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-PLUMBOOK-2012/html/GPO-PLUMBOOK-2012.htm

Excel:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ye6z.png)
If I can get it so that it at least includes the office name next to the first entry of that subsection, I can fill in the blank rows of that column in excel.

I tried using various methods on Python to extract the data and reorganize it. Using namedtuple, I was able to sort the department names out in the txt file, but there were no distinguishing features of the office names, as they were all varying sizes, styles of text, and names.

Comment: The text form would not be hard to process, since it is rigidly formatted, but it may not be a good project for a beginner.  The information you need is all in nice columns, although you'll have to handle fields that overflow to the next line.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you very much for your response. Is there a straightforward way to capture fields that spill over multiple lines? Or does it depend on the contents?

Comment: use some OCR technologies

Comment: Well, it's not HARD, but it's not straightforward.  OCR is the wrong answer; this is not scans of printed data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you look at the MODs link which is just XML it has links to XML versions of the documents. If they are then the exercise is trivial using XSLT to create the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you 98% of the way there.  I'll try to walk you through the flow.

If you look at the file, you'll see that the data area consists of a title (in caps), a set of headers, and the data areas.  These three sections are separated by a line of 152 dashes.  I look for that marker.

With the data areas, there are multiple lines.  A starting line always has a dot in column 28, at the end of the location.  Sometimes the location is a ditto line ("Do...."); if we get that, we just reuse the previous location.  Sometimes the office is also a ditto line ("......do...."), so again we have to reuse the previous office.

If the line does not have a dot in column 28, then it is a continuation line.  Both the location and the office can be continued.  We just tack the stripped column onto the end of the previous data.

I save the data in a list of rows.  When it's all done, I dump the rows to a CSV file, which can be opened in Excel.

Please note that I did this because it looked fun.  I'm expecting YOU to handle the details to finish this.  I don't want you to ask me to fix trivial things like wrong column headers or wrong column order.

### Followup

I've now modified this to gather the departments as well.  The key to this kind of processing is to look for the rules -- what makes this line different from all the other lines?

```
import csv

# 1 31 55 98 108

phase = 0
marker = '-'*152
save = ''
location = ''
department = ''

DEBUG = 0

data = []
for line in open('x.txt'):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if 'APPENDIX' in line:
        break
    elif line == marker:
        if phase == 0:
            heading = save
        phase = (phase + 1) % 3
        department = ''
    elif phase == 0:
        save = line.strip()
    elif phase == 2:
        if not line:
            phase = 3
            continue
        if DEBUG:
            print(line)
# There are 3 possibilities:
# 1. The line begins with a location.
# 2. The line is a ditto.
# 3. The line is a name continuation.
        if len(line) > 27 and line[27] == '.':
            if line[0] != ' ':
                location = line[:28].rstrip('.')
            office1 = line[30:52].strip('. ')
            if not office1 == 'do':
               office = office1
            name = line[54:91].strip('.')
            appt = line[97:100].strip()
            pay = line[107:109].strip()
            if DEBUG:
                print( [heading, department, location, office, name, appt, pay] )
            data.append( [heading, department, location, office, name, appt, pay] )
        else:
            l1 = line[1:28].strip()
            o1 = line[31:54].strip()
            if l1:
                location = ' '.join((data[-1][1], l1))
                data[-1][1] = location
            if o1:
                office = ' '.join((data[-1][2], o1))
                data[-1][2] = office
    elif phase == 3:
        if not line:
            phase = 2
        else:
            if department:
                department += ' '
            department += line.strip()

print(len(data),'rows')

with open('xxx.csv','w') as file:
    fcsv = csv.writer( file )
    fcsv.writerow(['heading','department','location','office','name','appointment','pay'])
    fcsv.writerows(data)
```

Output:

```
heading,department,location,office,name,appointment,pay
ARCHITECT OF THE CAPITOL,,"Washington, DC Capitol.",Architect of the,Stephen T. Ayers,PAS,EX
GOVERNMENT ACCOUNTABILITY OFFICE,,"Washington, DC United States.",Comptroller General of,Gene L. Dodaro,PAS,EX
GOVERNMENT ACCOUNTABILITY OFFICE,,"Washington, DC General.",Deputy Comptroller,Vacant,PAS,EX
GOVERNMENT PRINTING OFFICE,OFFICE OF THE PUBLIC,"Washington, DC",Public Printer,Vacant,PAS,EX
GOVERNMENT PRINTING OFFICE,OFFICE OF THE PUBLIC,"Washington, DC",Deputy Public Printer,Davita E. Vance-Cooks,XS,EX
GOVERNMENT PRINTING OFFICE,OFFICE OF THE PUBLIC,"Washington, DC Documents.",Superintendent of,Mary Alice Baish,XS,SL
GOVERNMENT PRINTING OFFICE,OFFICE OF THE PUBLIC,"Washington, DC",Inspector General,Michael A. Raponi,XS,SL
GOVERNMENT PRINTING OFFICE,OFFICE OF THE PUBLIC,"Washington, DC the Public Printer.",Executive Assistant to,Heather M. Lawson,S,OT
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,,"Washington, DC",Librarian of Congress,James H. Billington,PAS,EX
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD,"Washington, DC Secretary of Treasury.","Ex Officio Member,",Timothy F. Geithner,XS,W
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD,"Washington, DC",Board Member,Joan W. Harris,PA,W
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD,"Washington, DC",Board Member,Vacant,PA,W
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD PERMANENT COMMITTEE FOR THE OLIVER WENDELL HOLMES DEVISE,"Washington, DC",Committee Member,Linda K. Kerber,PA,W
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD PERMANENT COMMITTEE FOR THE OLIVER WENDELL HOLMES DEVISE,"Washington, DC",Committee Member,Michael Les Benedict,PA,W
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD PERMANENT COMMITTEE FOR THE OLIVER WENDELL HOLMES DEVISE,"Washington, DC",Committee Member,Rachel F. Moran,PA,W
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD PERMANENT COMMITTEE FOR THE OLIVER WENDELL HOLMES DEVISE,"Washington, DC",Committee Member,Vacant,PA,W
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD PERMANENT COMMITTEE FOR THE OLIVER WENDELL HOLMES DEVISE AMERICAN FOLKLIFE CENTER,"Washington, DC",Trustee Member,Susan Hildreth,PA,W
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD PERMANENT COMMITTEE FOR THE OLIVER WENDELL HOLMES DEVISE AMERICAN FOLKLIFE CENTER,"Washington, DC",Trustee Member,Robert G. Stanton,PA,W
LIBRARY OF CONGRESS,TRUST FUND BOARD PERMANENT COMMITTEE FOR THE OLIVER WENDELL HOLMES DEVISE AMERICAN FOLKLIFE CENTER,"Washington, DC Chairman, National Endowment for the Arts.","Ex Officio Member,",Rocco Landesman,XS,W
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. This is extraordinarily helpful and certainly points me in the right direction. I will give it a try.

Comment: is it possible to add a column that notes the agency within the department that someone works in? Fr example, within the Government Printing Office department, there are some employees in "OFFICE OF THE PUBLIC" and some in "Office of the Chief of Staff." I tried to use spaces at the beginning of a line as a marker to add an additional phase for when these agency names appear, then repeat those until the next appears, as you did with the 'heading' column for departments, but the name continuation lines would also be captured. Unfortunately, only some of the agency names are in caps.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed those were extensions of the previous office name, but I see what you mean now.  I think that can be handled, because it's the only time in the data regions where there is a blank line.